# How do I read from /dev/ttyACM0 in Linux without a terminal emulator?

Tags: serial, arduino-due, linux

I just bought an Arduino Due and I'm having trouble reading from a simple serial IO program.

I have a SparkFun RedBoard which is like an Uno. With that, I just ran a "`stty`" command to configure the baud rate and other terminal settings, and then I could do "`cat /dev/ttyUSB0`". Actually I have a C++ program which opens "`/dev/ttyUSB01`" and reads from it like a normal file.

Now, with the Due, the device is "`/dev/ttyACM0`" and there have been a few snags. One of them is that after programming the Due, and running `stty`, I have to open `/dev/ttyACM0` using the `screen` program:

```
screen /dev/ttyACM0 115200
```

and then kill screen, before `cat /dev/ttyACM0` will work. Otherwise, `cat` prints out one byte and exits; rarely it prints out 10 bytes or a line, or sometimes it prints nothing.

This is a bit annoying and I can't figure out what `screen` is doing to the device which I can't seem to accomplish using `stty`. My `stty` command is:

```
sudo stty -F /dev/ttyACM* 115200 -parenb -parodd -cmspar cs8 -hupcl -cstopb cread clocal -crtscts \
-ignbrk brkint ignpar -parmrk -inpck -istrip -inlcr -igncr -icrnl ixon -ixoff -iuclc \
-ixany -imaxbel -iutf8 \
-opost -olcuc -ocrnl -onlcr -onocr -onlret -ofill -ofdel nl0 cr0 tab0 bs0 vt0 ff0 \
-isig -icanon iexten -echo echoe echok -echonl -noflsh -xcase -tostop -echoprt echoctl \
echoke -flusho -extproc
```

I got this by running `stty -a < /dev/ttyACM0` after using `screen` to initialize as above.

I thought it might have something to do with serial auto-reset, so I tried using a resistor between `3.3V` and `RESET`, but this did not fix the problem.

I should note that `cu` from the `uucp` package is able to read continuously from `/dev/ttyACM0`, but unlike `screen` it does not leave the terminal set up in such a way that a subsequent `cat` command will work.

```
$ cu -l /dev/ttyACM0 -s 115200
<continuous stream of data>
$ killall cu             # (from another shell)
$ cat /dev/ttyACM0 | hexdump -c
<e.g. 7 bytes>
$
```

With `screen`, `cat` would have printed an infinite stream. Any ideas how to accomplish this setup without using `screen`?

Comment: You can have stty dump the settings established by screen for future use. See its man page for details.

Comment: I thought you'd missed my use of `stty -a` but then I saw that there's a `stty -g` ("print all current settings in a stty-readable form"). It doesn't really seem to be documented, but now I see that I can pass the output of `stty -g` as an argument to `stty`: `stty "0:0:18b2:0:3:1c:7f:8:4:0:1:0:11:13:1a:0:12:f:17:16:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0" -F /dev/ttyACM0`. This indeed works, where copy-pasting from `stty -a` didn't work because I missed the `min 1` bit. However, I'm glad for @jantje's solution because now I understand what was going wrong and plus I have a readable command-line.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have had very similar problems with my yun(shields) and I found the stty command to be very crucial for a good working.
I use following command and it works with mega and due on the yun

```
stty -F ${PortName}  ${SerialSpeed}  raw -clocal -echo icrnl
```

Since I call these I can redirect from and to /dev/ttyxxx without problems.
As far as I can see you mis the raw.

Comment: That seems to work for me. In fact I narrowed it down a bit: if I just `stty -F /dev/ttyACM1 115200 min 1` then it works. The `min 1` is part of the definition of `stty raw`. So I guess the Arduino IDE was putting the terminal into a mode where reads could be non-blocking. I guess I'll use your whole `stty` command in the future though - the other options look useful, although may I ask why you have `icrnl`?

Anyway, thank you!

Comment: To be honest.... I think you understand far more about this then I do. I started like you; with running a program (minicom in my case) and then querying stty. After 2 years of playing with the yun shield I ended up with these. I'm happy to see they work for you as well. But it is based on trial and error not on knowing. So I can't answer your question.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure, but I confess I had a recent issue with a mysterious glitch appearing in my software-oscilloscpe trace around X=13. It went away when I removed the `icrnl` setting :)