# writing and uploading sketch as cpp file

Tags: arduino-uno, uploading, build

I want to use only `*.cpp` files and no `*.ino` anymore. I read a lot of stuff about how to upload c++ instead of arduino sketches. But still I was not able to find a step by step guide how to do it.

Actually I am developing my sketch within Spacemacs (Emacs) and uploading it with Arduino-Makefile (https://github.com/sudar/Arduino-Makefile)

When I now want to start a new project with only `*.cpp` and `*.h` files to use classes etc. how would I start? Does anybody has the time to describe a rough step-by-step without the trivial stuff?

Comment: `.ino` files _are_ C++ files. You could just rename your main C++ file with the `.ino` extension and compile it with the IDE or Sudar's Makefile. If you are not using the Arduino core library, a much simpler Makefile could do it.

Comment: yea but what about these `loop()` and `setup()` functions. I know I could write a `main()` function instead but well...there must be some kind of conventional interface so the microcontroller knows what to start running. Or are those two "arduino" functions wrapped by a `main()` function which just calls setup once and calls `loop()` in a while-loop?

Comment: If you're moving to a standalone project then why do you care what the Arduino libraries do? If you need the Arduino libraries then why are you moving to a standalone project?

Comment: I never said I want to skip the arduino library. Still want to use it but not in a ino file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See my post about [How the IDE organizes things](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/a/13182/10794).

Also see my [page about how to avoid the quirks of the IDE sketch file pre-preprocessing](http://www.gammon.com.au/forum/?id=12625).

You can certainly manage without .ino files. As Edgar Bonet says, they are really C++ files with certain pre-processing (see link above).

> but what about these loop() and setup() functions

Effectively, the Arduino IDE supplies a main function that looks like this:

```c++
int main ()
  {
  init ();    // initialize hardware, including timers and timer interrupts
  setup ();   // user setup
  while (true)
    loop ();  // stuff to be done repeatedly
  return 0;   // this will never be executed
  }
```

(It's slightly more complex, to allow for USB where applicable, but that is the idea).

> But still I did not found the step by step guide how to do it.

I'm pretty sure there are a lot of example "make" files around which show the idea.

I have an example [here](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/a/15898/10794).